# 0x80070002 Error when creating a new .Net Core project in VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, dnx

I get the **0x80070002** error every time I  try to create an ASP.NET Core project. I have installed the VS 2015 update 3 and Microsoft .NET Core Tools/Templates.

I ended up with a blank solution with all 3 ASP.NET Core Templates.
Checked the VS 2015 template folder for the corresponding files and it seems OK.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me. As a workaround, you can use `dotnet new -t web` or [yo aspnet](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet).

Comment: Thanks Nate, however I have thought of using the VS templates (for a reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few days internet hunting and no positive results tried following steps and got this working

- Step 1: Uninstalled DNVM (manual uninstall each version)
- Step 2: Uninstall all core prior updates (Except the Web Deployment Tool)
- Step 3: Delete 'ComponentModelCache' folders from AppData
- Step 4: Delete 'devenv.exe.config' from AppData
- Step 5: Upgrade DNVM to latest
- Step 6: Running the 'DotNetCore.1.0.0-Runtime-x64.exe'
- Step 7: Installed 'DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview'
- Step 8: Checked VS2015 setup if nothing missed out(in my case everything else was present)

Got everything working finally and didn't had to re-install/download VS 2015 CE.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following 2 things:

- Go to **VS Installation => Modify** and make sure that you check **Web Development Tools** (If you have not marked before).
- Make sure that you install the latest .NET Core tooling for Visual Studio from [here](http://dot.net/) and click on .NET Core.

I've also written a [blog post](http://kjanshair.azurewebsites.net/blog/aspnetcoresystem) where you can find how to prepare your system for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I have .both NET Core tooling and Web Development tools installed, however while running setup the installation took lot of time(several hours). Only my core templates are resulting in blank solution, rest everything is working fine. If you can suggest a way **(kind of Copy---> paste templates)** that would be good

Comment: Are the default ASP.NET Core templates running in your VS instance?

Comment: None of core templates running other .net/c# templates YES

Answer (score 0):

## This is for Windows installation

Before you try uninstalling/installing everything
Try this:

- go to the main page https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core
- **Do not run Step-by-Step installer** for some reason it is installing the tools and not the framework. Instead run the individual installers
- .NET Core 1.0.3 SDK - Installer (x64 / x86 .exe)
- Visual Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2) (x64 / x86 .exe)

## Mac Installation

The only issue I ran was that my local version of .net core was older and the Yeoman Generator is already using the new .csprj file (new to core lol) which force you to update to the latest version, so all I had to do was install the latest, for me at the time of this post is: .NET Core SDK 1.0 rc4 build 004771  https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc4-download.md

Comment: I guess the MS people have taken care of this in VS 2017 RC, However I would wait for some time to let the positive reviews float around about the same.

Comment: this is for 2015 not 2017. In my case after I installed 2017, because of the change in the project structure it broke 2015

Comment: Yeah got it, MS people love to re-arrange the same furniture in their living rooms too, :)